# ALINK : error AL1019: Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: directory, metadata, visual-studio-2022

I have an asp.net webform project that build on system1 but not on system2 (they both are windows 10 and visual studio 2022 Version 17.4.3) and when I build visual studio show an error in error list window :
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       **Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The file or directory is corrupted** and unreadable.  Modabber    D:\BehsamanCode\Modabber\Modabber.Web\ALINK"

Also it shows this error in the output window :
"ALINK : error AL1019: Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable"

I searched these errors and I enabled long path on windows10 and uncheck Sign the assembly but not work.

What should we do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but it resolved. I think system2 hard drive has a problem and after win10 repair it itself then restart windows the problem gone and project builded.